# document.getElementById returns [object HTMLTableCellElement]

Tags: javascript, html

Right now, I have this td:

```
<td id="setCustomer"><?= $customer ?></td>
```

Later down the page I have:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('setCustomer').onclick = function(){
var newOne = document.getElementById('setCustomer');
console.log("var newOne is "+newOne); 
}
</script>
```

When I click the table cell that contains this customer name, the function launches and spits out:

```
var newOne is [object HTMLTableCellElement]
```

instead of:

```
var newOne is ACME CORP.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need the content of the element, not the element itself:

```
var newOne = document.getElementById('setCustomer').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Now I get `var newOne is undefined `